# Unity C# Editor script help creating a script object like ui button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity when you add a button to the ui you get a script that gives you an option to add items to the OnClick() method.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sjsy.jpg

I would like to do something similar if it is possible.
I would like to have a script that has a list in the script of all the effects that the block can be damaged by.
I want to be able to just drag different scripts into this list, or add them by clicking the + sign and selecting from a list like the button script.
Effects that would be included in the list would be like fire, lightning, acid, etc.
An example mockup image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbFtB.jpg

Edit: Had the wrong mockup image

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but please let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use unity's default drawing of the array and a PropertyDrawer, it won't give you the "+" and "-" button directly but it will allow you to draw the inspector for you class however you want. And then you can use either the "Size" of the array or the right clicking each value to duplicate or remove it.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html

This should give you an example to get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to make your GameObject's public so that you can click and drag items in the inspector?

So it would be something like this

```
List<Effects> effects; 
public GameObject object; 
public bool fire; 
pbulic bool lightening;
```

Then the object above you can set it up, by clicking on a gameobject in the scene and dragging it into the inspector. Also for the bools, you can turn fire or lightening on or false using true or false bools. Does that make sense?

Also, you can have a list of effects where you can save your fire, lightening objects to.

Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: I have the effects as public and it shows up in the editor, but I cannot drag & drop an effect script into it. I can only drag & drop unity objects that have an effect script attached to it.
What shows in the editor:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/FfU4S.jpg

And  the empty window I get when clicking to add an effect:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/cIXMf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a public **script** cause it **is not a variable**.

Anyway you can use the function getComponent http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html

You can try something like that :

```
// Drag and drop your gameobject containing your script
public GameObject obj;

void start()
{
  obj.getComponent<NameOfYourScript>()."function or variable in your script";
}
```